# Find IL instruction by address from exception stacktrace

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have an exception stacktrace from xamarin-android release build. There no filenames and line numbers:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object
>       at Test.Foo (Test.Bar bar) <0x995f8000 + 0x00248> in  <filename unknown>:0
>       at ...

Is it possible to find IL code by address (`0x995f8000 + 0x00248`) in DLL that triggers this exception?

Comment: Where do you get the exception stack trace?

Comment: @jzeferino, I get it from `adb logcat`

Comment: And in that stack strace you don't have any more relevant information? You could decompile your APK with a IL decompiler a try to search by address.

Comment: @jzeferino, I'm able to decompile and find class and method by name. I make some assumptions, where `NullReferenceException` can be occured. But I want to know exactly where it happend. I've tried with DotPeek and IlDasm, but can't find how to navigate to this `0x995f8000 + 0x00248`

Comment: Don't you have and offset of the instructions? Did you search for the offset 0x00248?

Comment: @jzeferino, are you speaking about this lines: `IL_0000` ? Max number in this method is `IL_015d`, so I can't navigate to 0x00248

Comment: Yes, i was talking about that. Why don't you use Crashlytics or HockeyApp into your app to get crash reports?

Comment: @jzeferino, Thanks for recomendations. I'm already using xamarin-insights. Unfortunately crash happend not in main project, but in compiled dll library.